# Problems using routes in Laravel in web.php file

Tags: php, laravel, routes, frameworks

I'm completely new in Laravel and I'm getting troubles with routes basic usage. Despite I follow the official documentation, routes just don't work.

the line

```
Route::get('foo',   function()  {return 'Hello  World';});
```

doesn't work. When I browse to

http://laravel/foo

I get a not found error.

Only

```
Route::get('/'
```

will properly shows the Hellow World message.

I use the default .htaccess file provided by Laravel, I'm running this test under a local Apache server on a Windows 10 machine. The laravel virtual hosting is properly defined in the configuration files and in the host file.

Can anyone explain me why I cannot use custom routes?

Comment: you try press php artisan route:list to ensure that route foo exists

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to all but I actually found the cause of my problem!!!

It just was a server configuration problem with Apache. Basically I had to enable mod_rewrite in my httpd.conf file in order to allow .htaccess to be ran locally. Essentially I had to add something like the following at the end of my configuration file

```
<Directory D:/pages_perso/Websites/practices/php/lara8>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride All  
</Directory>
```

I'm sure I'm not the only one facing this problem. Surely other people might. Then, as soon as I found the solution I posted it, in the hope to help other people as well!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a `/` in front of your route path?

So:

```
Route::get('foo',   function()  {return 'Hello  World';});
```

Becomes:

```
Route::get('/foo',   function()  {return 'Hello  World';});
```